# vba changing columns based on cell from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Copy_Data()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C6").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("b55").Value 
    Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C10").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("c55").Value 
      Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C8").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("d55").Value 

Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C35").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("b51").Value
    Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C39").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("c51").Value
      Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C37").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("d51").Value

      Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C64").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("b50").Value
    Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C68").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("c50").Value
      Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C66").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("d50").Value

        Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C93").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("b52").Value
    Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C97").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("c52").Value
      Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C95").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("d52").Value

                       Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C122").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("b53").Value
    Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C126").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("c53").Value
      Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C124").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("d53").Value

         Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C151").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("b54").Value
    Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C155").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("c54").Value
      Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C153").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("d54").Value

                       Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C180").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("b56").Value
    Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C184").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("c56").Value
      Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C182").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("d56").Value

                       Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C209").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("b57").Value
    Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("C213").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("c57").Value
      Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range("c211").Value = Worksheets("Cleaned").Range("d57").Value


  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am having issues setting the `weekly formula` range column based on the "cleaned" work sheet cell that `H25`. I have it already setup to produce the correct letter for the column I want. I just don't know script it into this macro. ie rookie at this, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In your code you are not doing reference to `H25` can you clarify your question?

Comment: yeah sorry I want reference h25 from "cleaned" worksheet. to change "weekly formula" "C6" for example to "d6" and so on for all the "weekly formula" locations. so if h25 is "d" it changes them all to "d". if h25 is set to "E" it would change them all to "E6", "E10", "E8". I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read `H25` into a variable and use that in your range addresses (I have used Activesheet but change as appropriate to the sheet name where you are picking up the `H25` value from):

```
Sub test()

Dim sourceCol As String

sourceCol = ActiveSheet.Range("H25").Value2

Worksheets("Weekly formula").Cells(209, sourceCol).Value = ........


End Sub
```

Or

```
Worksheets("Weekly formula").Range(sourceCol & 209).Value
```

Comment: I would consider putting some error handling in to confirm that H25 has a valid column reference in it if I were you.